# CSS available but not rendering when push to production [Rails app]

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

For some strange reason I cannot get my Rails app to render the CSS files on the server when running in production mode. I am running a Passenger + Nginx setup.

When I hit the public URL, I can see the app. The problem is, no styles are being applied. When I use the Chrome dev tools to view the CSS being rendered, I see that the file is present on the server, with all the CSS in it.

However, if I look at a specific component, I see something strange:

```
a:-webkit-any-link {
color: -webkit-link;
text-decoration: underline;
cursor: auto;
}
```

Everything says "webkit...style".  Or "user-agent". I've never seen that before?

Again, the CSS precompiled files are definitely on the server - I can access them.  (assets/application-45fdaf.....css).

Here is the head of the template being rendered:

```
<head>
  <title>Walter - <%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "CRM App" %></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>

  <!-- Stylesheets -->
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Apple icons -->
  <%= favicon_link_tag('apple-icon-57.png', rel: 'apple-touch-icon', type: 'image/png', size: "57x57") %>
  <%= favicon_link_tag('apple-icon-72.png', rel: 'apple-touch-icon', type: 'image/png', size: "72x72") %>
  <%= favicon_link_tag('apple-icon-114.png', rel: 'apple-touch-icon', type: 'image/png', size: "114x114") %>
  <%= favicon_link_tag('apple-icon-144.png', rel: 'apple-touch-icon', type: 'image/png', size: "144x144") %>

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <%= favicon_link_tag '/favicon.ico' %>
</head>
```

(I've tried setting static assets to true and false in production.rb, but it doesn't seem to matter).

It's like the app isn't looking within the public/assets folder for the CSS. What is even more strange is that the images render fine.  And it does look like the app is looking in the right spot:

```
<link href="/assets/application-f0659345b965e7ce36fb30edf04896c6.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Thanks.

**Update**

When using `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>` in production mode, something is causing this to return the stylesheet as text/plain instead of text/css.

Why is this happening?

**Fixed**

Apparently you definitely need to include the mime.types file is the nginx.conf.  I may have commented it out at some point, or documentation just needs to get better. Either way, this fixed it.  Without that line included, it can't translate CSS files.

Comment: What does the stylesheet_link_tag render?

Comment: renders this `<link href="/assets/application-f0659345b965e7ce36fb30edf04896c6.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">`. I am able to run the app fine in development mode. Something strange going on with production.

Comment: And when you go to the Network tab on Chrome what do you see for that CSS file? 200, 404, 403?

Comment: I see 200. And it actually shows me the contents of the CSS file. Everything seems to be there.

Comment: And no missing body class or content div? Is the expected css on the body tag?

Comment: Nope doesn't appear anything is missing. I see a style in the HTML view and I see the style in the application.css, but no style actual renders.

Comment: I just booted up the production env locally and it works. Only when I deploy to the server does it not work. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Is the production server returning the css file with content-type text/css or application/octet-stream? The latter is apparently a common mistake but won't render in chrome.

Comment: I've tried Chrome, Firefox, Safari - it won't render CSS in any of them.

Comment: And what is the content type returned for the css file? Check the response headers in the network tab.

Comment: Oh damn - this is the problem.  It is returning text/plain instead of text/css.. What the heck? How do we fix that?

Comment: I found the issue. Posted a fix above. Really appreciate your help. Wouldn't have even none what to look for. Thanks again!

Comment: I am having this same problem. However, the mime type of my css file is text/css.  So this is still broken for me :(