# Rails & Nginx & Passenger css and javascript loading but not being applied in production

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, nginx, asset-pipeline, passenger

This is a Rails 4 project being served by Nginx + Passenger. Works perfect when rails environment is development. I think the compressed javascript file is loading correctly because the ajax calls that are supposed to execute on page load are working perfectly.  The problem is that none of the CSS rules are being applied to the document.

I have the exact same issue as described here: [CSS available but not rendering when push to production [Rails app]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292459/css-available-but-not-rendering-when-push-to-production-rails-app/20296069#comment41967090_20296069) except my css file's mime type is correct.

Here is my config/environments/production.rb

```
  config.eager_load = true
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.css_compressor = :yui
```

Assets have been precompiled correctly.  Here is the relevant served html link/script spec:

```
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application-3d4e35bd2c14a288b7d2ff3f5dd8f5c4.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application-ab6bb9f22b553eba6788881b0b36f94c.js"></script>
```

Nginx config:

```
http {
    passenger_root /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/passenger-4.0.53;
    passenger_ruby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/wrappers/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name subdomain.domain.com;
        root /home/user/rails-project/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;
    }
}
```

Here here is the css request/response (notice the correct mime-types):
[image]

The CSS file is correctly compiled, and all my sass and css rules and present (combination sass and css).

Comment: How are you deploying? Capistrano? Try setting `config.serve_static_assets` to `false`.

Comment: Does setting `config.assets.compile = true` fixes that?

Comment: Can you also post the full HTML contents? Also, I assume you tried Ctrl+F5 to clear your cache and reload everything? Either way you don't want your production app serving static assets, nginx will do that. `config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Accel-Redirect"`. If your browser can receive the CSS file and read it properly then by all means it should be working. Is your production server the same machine as your development server? Is the <link> tag in the header?

Comment: Not using capistrano, deploying by manually pulling from git repop.  config..assets.compile = true has no affect.  In regards to Jake's suggestions: the producton and development machines are not the same; the link tag is def. in the header.  I won't post the html, but I will tell you that I passed the HTML in an HTML validator and there were no errors (just a few warnings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the  CSS compiler was most likely the source of this issue.  When i had the compiler set like this:

`config.assets.css_compressor = :yui`

The css files seemed to be minified and compiled without issue.  However, once I removed that line (I assume it defaults to the sass gem for compression), then when i tried `rake assets:precompile`, I was getting the following error:

```
➜  stylesheets git:(master) ✗ rake assets:precompile
(in /home/ubuntu/spice-conduit)
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "    filter: progid": expected ";", was ": DXImageTransf..."
  (in /home/ubuntu/spice-conduit/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
(sass):3566
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1147:in `expected'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1085:in `expected'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1080:in `tok!'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:586:in `block in declaration_or_ruleset'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1123:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1123:in `rethrow'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:592:in `declaration_or_ruleset'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:554:in `block_child'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:546:in `block_contents'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:535:in `block'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:529:in `ruleset'
```

So apparently there were compliation errors that were not displaying when using the yui compressor? These compilation errors occur when compiling bootstrap and font-awesome css files.

**How I fixed:**

1. Removed all Bootstrap and Font-awesome gems from project
2. Downloaded latests Bootstrap and Font-awesome css files from their github sites
3. Placed files in vendor/assets
4. Removed all instances of DXImageTransform from the files.
5. Precompiled and deployed assets

This solution is not idea because now I have to manually maintain the bootstrap and font-awesome asset files. For the time being, however, at least my app serves compressed and minified assets!

Answer (score 0):

Static files should be served from disk directly, so make sure Nginx set to have enough permissions to get access to the files. It also recommended to make its own location for static:

```
location /assets/  {
  root /home/user/rails-project/public;
  gzip_static on;
  expires max;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
  access_log /dev/null;
}
```

Assets Pipeline generates gzip versions of compressed JS and CSS files, so "gzip_static" directive helps you to serve gzip straight away with no overhead. Your Nginx should be compiled with module --with-http_gzip_static_module to support that.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your answer.  I uninstalled, then reinstalled nginx with the gzip static module like you suggested.  This did not fix this issue.